# Find x given y on cumulative frequency graph

Tags: r, cdf

I'm deriving a CDF from a Kernel Smoothing distribution

Here's my setup

```
library("DiagTest3Grp", lib.loc='~/R/win-library/3.2")

data <- c(34,46,47,48,52,53,55,56,56,56,57,58,59,59,68)
bw <- BW.ref(data)
x0 <- seq(0, 100, .1) 
KS.cdfvec <- Vectorize(KernelSmoothing.cdf, vectorize.args = "c0")
x0.cdf <- KS.cdfvec(xx = data, c0 = x0, bw = bw)
plot(x0, x0.cdf, type = "l")
```

Produces graph

[image]

Yet, I'm so green I have no idea how to derive x given y (or vice versa), I'm hoping that since it's a simple x,y graph that I just need to look up a crosssection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value `y` in the CDF you want the corresponding value `x` in the pdf
that corresponds to this. You can just use `approx`, but since in `approx` you
specify `yout` not `xout`, just flip the inputs

```
> approx(y=x0, x=x0.cdf, xout=0.8)
$x
[1] 0.8

$y
[1] 58.95378
```

Remember that we flipped the inputs, so this means for the value 0.8 in the CDF
this corresponds to a value of `x=58.95378`. This also assumed that is this small region of the CDF linear interpolation is a reasonable approximation.

In the case that we have a value of `x` and simply want the associated value of the CDF, no argument flipping is necessary, so you can just use

```
> approx(x=x0, y=x0.cdf, xout=55)
$x
[1] 55

$y
[1] 0.5090248
```

Comment: thank you for half the problem.  I tried approx(x=y0, x=x0.cdf, y=77) and got Error in approx(x = y0, x = x0.cdf, y = 77) : 
  formal argument "x" matched by multiple actual arguments  also approx(y=5, x=x0.cdf, xout=y0) and got Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ... I'll look up approx function.  I really appreciate this!

Comment: I am confused with what `y0` is here since it is not specified in your question? But yes please read the documentation for `?approx`. `x` and `y` here correspond to vectors of points, i.e. `(x[1], y[1])`, and `xout` are the x values for which you want corresponding y values

Comment: I'm trying to derive x given y and y given x.  You showed me how to derive y given x, but not vice versa

Comment: Ahh, here you would just call `approx` directly, I edited my response accordingly

Comment: `approx` is definitely a nice way to go. However, I wonder if it is possible to make a table of x-values and then compute the y-values. Then, place x's and y's into a data.frame, and then query the x associated with a given y of interest. Of course, this estimate is going to be more rough than `approx, but it might work when a function isn't nicely defined like CDF given here.

Answer (score 2):

Try quantile...

```
> data <- c(34,46,47,48,52,53,55,56,56,56,57,58,59,59,68)
> quantile(ecdf(data), .5)
    50%
    56
```